# Why does the code here create a non-used variable `context`?

Tags: odoo

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/addons/sale/wizard/sale_make_invoice_advance.py#L79-L86

```
    context = {'lang': order.partner_id.lang}
    if self.advance_payment_method == 'percentage':
        amount = order.amount_untaxed * self.amount / 100
        name = _("Down payment of %s%%") % (self.amount,)
    else:
        amount = self.amount
        name = _('Down Payment')
    del context
```

I'm quite familiar with Python so I think the `context` has not been used in the code above. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

After reading the code at https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/11.0/odoo/tools/translate.py#L387-L393

I've found the answer is: the underscore(`_`) function will use the context.lang setting for the translation. It will get the value of `context` from call stack.

Comment: That's correct the down payment strings will be translated to the orders customer language. It has to be changed, because usually the language in context is the users language.